# Triggering a bootstrap modal via a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

This project is an already built online shop. when a user clicks on a product - it runs an ajax request behind the scenes and pulls a modal window with product details.

The link the user clicks on looks like this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="{{ url('/shop/'.$shopid.'/product/ajax/'.$product['id']) }}" data-target="#productSetailsModalAjax"> </a>
```

Now the user has the ability to enter his name and email address inside a form and request a link of the product's page so he can review the product anytime.

The question is how do i generate a link that when clicked from a remote location will trigger the modal and act as like a user has clicked it while browsing the website?

i've tried giving the link above a custom id, so the link would become `<a id="trigger_modal_1" data-toggle="modal" ...` but no luck, when pressed from the email it just goes to `http://www.example.com#trigger_modal_1`.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Try adding an onclick event to your anchor click and use preventDefault

Comment: Your JavaScript should check what is the hash parameter of the page on load and open the popup with respective data...

Comment: @TJ  thanks ! i think that will do, why didn't i think about it earlier :)